# How to access a specific children in react and apply specific css?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hi guys i have two (on component StyledCompare) childrens here

```
<StyledContent
      $fullHeight={fullHeight}
      $align={align}
      $compare={compare}
      $className={className}
      {...restProps}
  >
   <StyledCompare> {children} </StyledCompare>
</StyledContent>
```

When i console.log(children) it returns me two distinct object (each children  = 5 divs that returns each one 1 component) and i want to know if i can for exemple get children number one and number two, so i can apply different css for each one

This is the css that i built (a grid) on StyledContent

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
```

and this is the css that i want to do on StyledCompare

```
export const StyledCompare = styled.div`
For the first children : grid-area: 1 / 3 / 6 / 5;
For the second children: grid-area: 1 / 6 / 6 / 8;
`;
```

I tried the tags "&:first-children" and "&:last-element" something and it doesnt do anything. Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i used it:

```
.left-inner-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #450037;
}

.left-inner-container:nth-of-type(3n+1) {background-color: #ff5e39;}
.left-inner-container:nth-of-type(3n+2) {background-color: #00d2d1;}
.left-inner-container:nth-of-type(3n+3) {background-color: #ffffff;}
```

left-inner-container is the class given to the div where i was rendering the elements

Comment: yeah but your code only works with ```` <div> <p>First child</p> <p>Second child</p>```` no ? Mine is <div>{children}</div>

Comment: use this seudo selector for the element that you want to change classes on :nth-of-type(3n+1), it is not element dependent as far as you are rendering them correctly.

Comment: wghat is 3n+1 means here ?

Comment: n is the elementIndex

Comment: It doesnt work with my code unfortunately. I need a way to distinguish children for each other and put them in different div